# Inconsistent Firebase JSON files generated programmatically vs. through Firebase GUI

Tags: firebase, plist

I'm currently using the `firebase apps:sdkconfig ANDROID --json --project <project_id>`  and `firebase apps:sdkconfig IOS --json --project <project_id>` commands to create the plist and android.json files for my Firebase project.

Previously, after running these commands, I would see the project email and public facing name under project settings. However, I've noticed that now I have to enable the Google login option in order to fill in these fields.
The problem arises when I fill in the email and name under authentication > Google in the Firebase GUI. It prompts me to download new plist and android.json files, which are different from the ones created using the Firebase CLI command. Additionally, I've observed that the old plist and android.json files were relatively small (around 1-3 KB), whereas the new files are over 700 KB in size.

I would like to understand why I'm receiving different JSON files when generating them programmatically versus downloading them from the Firebase GUI. The new plist and android files have the same values as before but also include additional key-value pairs.

Is there a way to programmatically obtain the new plist and json files? Furthermore, why does Firebase require me to download these new files?

Please see screenshots available for the old and new plist files, which clearly show the additional keys. The values are same but there are additional keys.

**GUI downloaded plist file:**

[image: GUI downloaded plist file]

**Programatically created plist file:**

[image: rogramatically created plist file:]